# How can I remove higher order term using SymPy? .removeO() does not work here

Tags: python, sympy, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to plot the series form of an ODE's solution using SymPy, and I need to remove the 'O' term before plotting.

```py
from IPython.display import display
from sympy import *
from sympy.plotting import plot

x = Function('x')
t = Symbol('t')
ode = Derivative(x(t),t) + t * x(t) - t**3

sol_series = dsolve(ode, hint='1st_power_series', n=8, ics={x(0): 1})
res = sol_series.removeO()
```

But here comes error

```sh
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-2775b6fd4150> in <module>
----> 1 res = sol_series.removeO()
      2 display(res)

AttributeError: 'Equality' object has no attribute 'removeO'
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the return from `dsolve` is an `Eq` (equation object) and the `removeO` method is for `Expr` so you should call `removeO` in the rhs of the equation:

```
In [5]: res = Eq(sol_series.lhs, sol_series.rhs.removeO())                                                                                                    

In [6]: res                                                                                                                                                   
Out[6]: 
          6      4    2    
         t    3⋅t    t     
x(t) = - ── + ──── - ── + 1
         16    8     2
```