# How to remove "O()" inside sympy equation

Tags: python, sympy, numerical-methods

I tried to get rid "O()" from my output function, i already found a way to used ".removeO()" from another question with the same problem, but it keep said that 'Equality' object has no attribute 'O'. Any other solution?

```
import sympy as sy
from IPython.display import display
t=sy.symbols('t')
y = sy.Function('y')
pdb=sy.Eq(y(t).diff(t)-5*sy.exp((-0.2)*t**2)+y(t)**2,0)
fungsi_eksak=sy.dsolve(pdb,y(t), ics={y(0): 0})
display(fungsi_eksak)
```

Output:

```
()=5−8.66666666666667^3+17.3533333333333^5+(^6)
```

After add ".removeO()" syntax

```
import sympy as sy
from IPython.display import display
t=sy.symbols('t')
y = sy.Function('y')
pdb=sy.Eq(y(t).diff(t)-5*sy.exp((-0.2)*t**2)+y(t)**2,0)
fungsi_eksak=sy.dsolve(pdb,y(t), ics={y(0): 0})
fungsi_eksak=fungsi_eksak.removeO()
display(fungsi_eksak)
```

output

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-23-98e49ce20b58> in <module>
      5 pdb=sy.Eq(y(t).diff(t)-5*sy.exp((-0.2)*t**2)+y(t)**2,0)
      6 fungsi_eksak=sy.dsolve(pdb,y(t), ics={y(0): 0})
----> 7 fungsi_eksak=fungsi_eksak.removeO()
      8 display(fungsi_eksak)

AttributeError: 'Equality' object has no attribute 'removeO'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove higher order term using SymPy? .removeO() does not work here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62385854/how-can-i-remove-higher-order-term-using-sympy-removeo-does-not-work-here)

Comment: Your equation does not have a symbolic solution. The power series expansion is a kind of numerical solution, is it the correct one for your purposes? Also, the displayed power series coefficients hint that they might grow rapidly, so that the radius of convergence will be rather small. // This is a Ricatti equation, with `y=u'/u` you get `u''=exp(-t**2/5)*u`, `u'(0)=0, u(0)=1`, which will have slightly more regular solutions.